# How to remove all inherited permissions for directory with SubInAcl.exe?

Tags: windows, inheritance, permissions, icacls, subinacl

How to remove all inherited permissions for directory with SubInAcl.exe?

I can do this with icacls by using /inheritance:r

Is there a way to do the same with SubInAcl?

Answer (score 0):

/perm should work here. I'd be very careful with it though. :)